# JXLS can't read number whose length is greater than 10 correctly

Tags: java, excel, jxls

I am using `jxls` for reading data from excel file. But there is something wrong when I tried to read a number like `12345678912`: it would be transfer to `1.2345678E10` unless I set the format of this column to `Text`.

Is there anything I can do to solve this problem without setting the column to `Text`?

Anything help would be appreciated.

Comment: What data type you used for it ?

Comment: use long data type and let me know whether it works @Chao

Comment: It's `String`,but it's not the problem.

Comment: I have tried,it doesn't work @Hariharan

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue..
you can fix this by using `NumberEval` of `org.apache.poi`

Find the code below

```
 NumberEval t=new NumberEval(1.2345678E10);
 String temp= t.getStringValue(); //will give you exact string value and you can cast it to long
```